# Django-allauth creating custom registration form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I want to create a signup form with additional fields. I am using django-allauth.

When I try to signup as a normal user I get this errror:

```
[01/Oct/2020 12:28:15] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 438
Internal Server Error: /accounts/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 215, in dispatch
    return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 81, in dispatch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 193, in dispatch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 104, in post
    response = self.form_valid(form)
  File "/Users/home/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 231, in form_valid
    self.user = form.save(self.request)
AttributeError: 'CustomSignupForm' object has no attribute 'save'
[01/Oct/2020 12:28:24] "POST /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 13665
```

I can create superuser. When creating superuser, it demands email but when logging in, it demands username. But I can enter email as username and log in successfully.

forms.py: (Got this snippet from https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1412)

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last name')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user.save()
```

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none' 

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile-messages'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'homepage'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'core.forms.CustomSignupForm'}
```

Comment: Is this setting correct `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'core.forms.CustomSignupForm'}`? Do you have an app called `core` where your form is located?

Comment: @Ralf Yes it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. My current code is:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```